# How to select a group of words in a URL with a Regular Expression

Tags: analytics

I need your help regarding a regular expression. I am trying to select only the beginning of this URL : **/senlis-60/87865063.htm** (Senlis-60) in one of my Google Analytics Widgets. I want to apply an expression that could work with other locations : Senlis or Paris or Bordeaux or other cities (I am in France).

I can't use basic filters because they are not as advanced as I thought so I am thinking of using a regular expression as a filter. The only big problem is that I am a real rookie concerning regular expressions.... I have some basic skills to understand it but not sufficient to create an expression.

Could you help me to understand and create this expression please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Just to clarify, you are trying to match the name of the city including the "-60", ie. {city}-60. Is that correct?</strike>

In that case you can try this regex:

```
[a-zA-Z]*-60
```

This matches 0 to an infinite number of letters (upper and lower case) and the "-60", eg. paris-60, bordeaux-60.

If you want to include the rest of the pathname, like the /87865063.htm, then you can make your regex this:

```
[a-zA-Z]*-60\/(.*)\.htm
```

This matches the same regex as above, including a "/{anything}.htm", eg. bordeaux-60/blahblah.htm or senlis-60/3by23.htm. Note that the (.*) above matches absolutely anything and everything!

If you need more help, feel free to PM me.

Hope this helps!

Try this:

```
\/[a-zA-Z]+-[0-9]+\/(.*)
```

Here is what that matches: a forward slash + one or more letters + a hyphen + one or more numbers + a forward slash + anything else.

Hope this helps.